# Зачем столько действий?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация

Периодически в истории изменений попадаются пачки действий [типа таких](/posts/2286/revisions):

> - Сообщение разблокировано участником Nick Volynkin♦
>     произошло 4 часа назад
> - Уведомление было удалено Комментарии не по теме пользователем Nick Volynkin♦
>     произошло 4 часа назад
> - Сообщение заблокировано участником Nick Volynkin♦ 
>     произошло 4 часа назад
> - Добавлено предупреждение Комментарии не по теме пользователем Nick Volynkin♦
>     произошло 4 часа назад
> - Модератор переместил комментарии в чат
>     произошло 4 часа назад

Что это за действия с предупреждениями и блокировками, зачем они нужны и как связаны с перемещением комментариев в чат?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В следующий раз вы можете просто спросить меня в чате. Но раз уж опубликовали на Мете, пускай этот ответ будет инструкцией по чтению истории сообщения.

> - Модератор переместил комментарии в чат
>     произошло 4 часа назад

Переместил драму из комментариев в чат. Удалил комментарии. Это два самостоятельных действия:

- перенос просто создает чат с комментариями и выдает всем участникам право на запись в чате. (Это нужно для низкореповых).
- потом нужно вручную удалить комментарии. Удаление каждого комментария если и логируется, то не в этом месте.

> - Сообщение заблокировано участником Nick Volynkin♦
>     произошло 4 часа назад
> - Добавлено предупреждение Комментарии не по теме пользователем Nick Volynkin♦
>     произошло 4 часа назад

Заблокировал комментарии, чтобы дальнейшее обсуждение велось в чате.

Потом подумал, что вроде бы горячие споры уже утихли. Проверил, что эта блокировка и голосовать запрещает, что нежелательно. Отменил блок:

> - Сообщение разблокировано участником Nick Volynkin♦
>     произошло 4 часа назад
> - Уведомление было удалено Комментарии не по теме пользователем Nick Volynkin♦
>     произошло 4 часа назад

Comment: А возможно ли сделать без блокировки? Ведь обычно к моменту переноса в вопросах уже тихо.

Comment: "Заблокировал комментарии, чтобы дальнейшее обсуждение велось в чате." - а почему две записи на одно действие? Можно ли их по отдельности получить?

Comment: @Qwertiy Блокировка влияет на возможность комментировать и голосовать, а уведомление - это подпись под запланированным вопросом. Аналогичная есть на закрытых. То и другое это результат нажатия одной кнопки, они и должны быть вместе.